# OpenCL error: undefined reference to `_Z12atom_cmpxchgPVU8CLglobalmmm()'

Tags: rust, opencl

When compiling the following OpenCL kernel:

```c
#pragma OPENCL EXTENSION cl_khr_int64_base_atomics : enable

__kernel void kernel(__global ulong* mem) {
    atom_cmpxchg(&mem[0], 0, 1);
}
```

I get the following error:

```
error: undefined reference to `_Z12atom_cmpxchgPVU8CLglobalmmm()'
```

I'm using OpenCL from Rust with the [OCL](https://github.com/cogciprocate/ocl) library. My OpenCL version is 1.2, my GPU is an Intel(R) Iris(TM) Graphics 550, I'm under macOS Sierra 10.12.1.

Comment: That is a Linker error. So, your compile phase seems to have passed correctly, but when the linker tried to assemble your binary it couldn't since some dynamic library is missing. You can try to run eg. `nm` over your local libs and try to find the .so file with the function in question. Once you have it and added it to your Cargo file then that should compile and link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the `CL_DEVICE_EXTENSIONS` of your device with `clGetDeviceInfo()`. `cl_khr_int64_base_atomics` may not be supported with this GPU under macOS.

Comment: The output I get indeed doesn't contain `cl_khr_int64_base_atomics`. Isn't that extension mandatory on OpenCL 1.2? Is there any workaround?

Comment: You could try updating macOS to get a newer GPU driver with more OpenCL support (but I have no idea what the chances of success are. Possibly 0, given the lackluster OpenCL support on macOS). Or maybe try Windows, if the extension is supported on your GPU there.

Comment: (Are you sure int 64 atomics are supported by the hardware architecture of your GPU?)

Comment: I do not know, no idea how I could check.  Thanks for the suggestions...